# Can't use try-with-resources or finally block

Tags: java, try-catch

My code is reading an HTML page from the web and I want to write good code, so I would like to close the resources using try-with-resources or finally block.

With the following code it seems impossible to use either of them to close "in".

```
    try {

        URL url = new URL("myurl");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                url.openStream()));

        String line = "";

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        in.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Would you be able to write the same code using try-with-resources or finally?

Comment: Unrelated question: Why do transform an `IOException` into a `RuntimeException`?

Comment: If you're changing it to a `RuntimeException`, make sure to include the original exception: `throw new RuntimeException(e);`

Comment: oh, yes, I forgot. I updated it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any particular difficulty with the following:

```
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new URL("myurl").openStream()))) {

        String line = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Is it not what you're looking for?